# Unable to select 'n' records in each item category with paging

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to select 5 records in each ItemCategoryID with paging, with the query below I am able to get 5 records in each category but paging is not working, as i have declared page size 10, but i am getting 19 records and @ItemCounter TotalCount is coming as 45... i m not getting how to solve it..here is the query:

```
DECLARE @PageIndex int = 1
DECLARE @PageSize int = 10
DECLARE @StartRow int
DECLARE @EndRow int
SET @StartRow = (@PageSize * (@PageIndex - 1))  + 1  
SET @EndRow = @PageSize * @PageIndex + 1
DECLARE @ItemCounter int
SELECT @ItemCounter = Count(*)FROM dbo.Auctions WHERE AuctionStatus=1;
WITH Auctions AS
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY ItemCategoryID  ORDER BY AuctionID) AS RowNumber,                 
            AuctionID, 
            ItemCategoryID  ,                             
            @ItemCounter TotalCount                         
            FROM Auctions                 
            WHERE                 
            AuctionStatus=1 
     )

    SELECT a.* FROM Auctions a  
    WHERE  a.RowNumber <=3 AND a.RowNumber 
    BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow - 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if possible can you provide the sample table data and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.RowNumber <=3 AND a.RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow - 1
```

What exactly do you expect from this? the row number has to be between start and end **AND** it has to be less than or equal to 3? What is start is 4? Any End above 3 is irrelevant.

I'm going to make a leap of faith here and say that the correctly stated requirement for your problem is:

- for each item category, return at most 4 auctions where status = 1
- page the result

so you obviously have two counters to consider, one for auctions within category and one for paging:

```
WITH Auctions AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY ItemCategoryID  ORDER BY AuctionID) AS AuctionNumber,                 
        AuctionID, 
        ItemCategoryID                             
        FROM Auctions                 
        WHERE                 
        AuctionStatus=1 
 ),
Paging as (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ItemCategoryID, AuctionID) as RowNumber
   , a.* 
  FROM Auctions a  
  WHERE AuctionNumber <= 3 
)
SELECT * 
  FROM Paging 
  WHERE  RowNumber BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow - 1;
```

Performance will be likely bad, but nobody can design any performance w/o data schema knowledge (table definition, indexes etc) which are missing from the problem statement.

TotalRecordCount:

```
WITH Auctions AS
(
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY ItemCategoryID  ORDER BY AuctionID) AS AuctionNumber,                 
    AuctionID, 
    ItemCategoryID  ,                             
  FROM Auctions                 
  WHERE AuctionStatus=1 
)
SELECT @total = COUNT(*) 
 FROM Auctions a  
 WHERE AuctionNumber <= 3;
```

Comment: thanks @Remus, how can i get  "TotalRecordCount" of Paging table without using group by clause, please excuse my mistakes as i m newbie in writing sql.